# Javascript - find out when external clipboard content changed?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a web-based application that needs listen to changes of the system's clipboard.

Specifically, when the user copies data into the clipboard (in an external application, so not copied directly from my own web app), I need some way in my web app to be notified of this ("clipboard data has just changed") & a way to get the data that was copied.

Is this somehow possible in JavaScript?

My gut feeling says no due to security reasons, but maybe there's some way to get this done without having to rely on any major other non-javascript techniques?

Thanks

Comment: No, due to security reasons. The only way would be to get the user to install a custom browser extension.

Comment: Check the experimental [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData) ([suport](https://caniuse.com/#search=clipboardData)). *Note: I'm not saying this to be possible, but pointing out a possible way...*

Comment: Unfortunately the Clipboard API can't read clipboard contents before the user pastes it manually.

Comment: @JJJ I wouldn't say *unfortunately* here, I would be pretty frightened if any script could read my clipboard at any time.

Comment: Unfotunately for the OP – fortunately for the Internet population.